# Multi-platform encryption suite with argon2 support

Tags: windows-10, command-line, encryption

I'm looking for a command line tool, with native Windows 10 support, which allow me to generate encryption keys with [argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) and to subsequently encrypt/decode files or volumnes.

As a key requirement, I don't want the suite to use persistent storage in its operation, in any way or form; all temporary files should reside in memory. Ideally, I want to run the suite off a RAM disk (of which I ideally could disable the use of swap space on disk).

I've come across an [argon2 utility](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2) (with native- Linux and OSX support) which merely generates hashes:

```
Usage:  ./argon2 [-h] salt [-i|-d|-id] [-t iterations] [-m memory] [-p parallelism] [-l hash length] [-e|-r] [-v (10|13)]
        Password is read from stdin
Parameters:
        salt            The salt to use, at least 8 characters
        -i              Use Argon2i (this is the default)
        -d              Use Argon2d instead of Argon2i
        -id             Use Argon2id instead of Argon2i
        -t N            Sets the number of iterations to N (default = 3)
        -m N            Sets the memory usage of 2^N KiB (default 12)
        -p N            Sets parallelism to N threads (default 1)
        -l N            Sets hash output length to N bytes (default 32)
        -e              Output only encoded hash
        -r              Output only the raw bytes of the hash
        -v (10|13)      Argon2 version (defaults to the most recent version, currently 13)
        -h              Print argon2 usage
```

Windows doesn't seem to be supported natively; only as a [node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/argon2).

The tool that I'm looking for should also take care of the encoding part.

Ideally, I'd want the tool to also generate (and store) the salt randomly:

```
> tool --argon2 --auto-salt --aes128 fileToEncrypt "passphrase" > encryptedFile
```

Comment: argon2 is a key derivation function, it is not enough just by itself to handle encryption/decryption needs.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Yes, I'm aware of that. I'm looking for a suite which implements one.

Comment: It is planned for openssl: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/4091   If you are ready to build programs, there are libraries for it, like `Crypt::Argon2`  in Perl or directly `password_hash` in PHP. Both these languages also implements all the other building blocks to handle encryption, decryption, signatures, etc.